# Sphinx не запускается индексация на windows 7, ошибки не отображаются

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Установил sphinx, запустил службу

```
C:\Sphinx\bin\searchd --install --config C:\Sphinx\sphinx.conf --servicename SphinxSearch
```

все ок, далее запускаю индексацию

```
C:\Sphinx\bin\indexer --all --config C:\Sphinx\sphinx.conf
```

и ни ответа ни привета, команда проходит без всяких сообщений.

На другой машине с таким же конфигом все норм.